# Nginx, unable to fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. I am working with an ubuntu 14.4 instance on amazon EC2. I've got everything working OK in testing, however after putting my django app online, I noticed that the server was returning:

```
 HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
```

When I logged into my ubuntu EC2 instance, I restarted uwsgi and nginx and got:

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ workon env1 
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini --daemonize=/var/log/yourproject.log
 [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart /tp/m
 sudo: unable to fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

What is going wrong? How can I fix this?

edit:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          992M       192M       799M       360K        37M        75M
-/+ buffers/cache:        79M       913M
Swap:           0B         0B         0B

(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-28-196 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x
86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What instance size are you using? small instances like micro don't have enough memory for all types of applications.

Comment: I am using a micro size, but its a very small django app which hits an api and returns a single response once every few minutes. No db involved. I've had it working before so I know it can work on a micro size instance.

Comment: You may need to check your thread and memory settings to limit the number of threads being created. Swap can be enabled if it not already, but that will be pretty slow if you end up hitting too much.

Comment: I'm totally new to server management , coming from php and python app development. Can you give me some basic commands or locations to look at?

Comment: Wow new problem, I tried sshing into the ec2 command line and its timing out so I can't run any commands. I'll reboot the ubuntu instance.

Comment: when I ssh in I get: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Most webserver / app server configurations have ways to limit threads or workers. You will have to look at the documentation for the systems you are using as to the configuration options you need for this.

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure that the system has not ran out of memory using `free -h` and that there are no process memory limits you are hitting, you can check that using `ulimit -a`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you enable swap if you still have disk space (like 1GB), some applications need more memory to initialize but after that it need a lot less memory, thus swap can help you survive that period.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `limite-as = 1024` in `mysite_uwsgi.ini`.